# Jquery load animation

Tags: jquery

Almost finished my site but a have this fatal error I don't know how to solve

I've used a guide from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

But I can't get it to work.
I would be really happy I you guys could help.

here is the link to the page where i'm trying to get it to work http://www.matskruger.dk

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="LeftPane">
    <div id="Logo">
        <h1>Mats Ulrik Krüger</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="HorzMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#JO">JO Informatik</a></li>
            <li><a href="#AnnDig">Annemette Digmann</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ContentPane">
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#MainMenu li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #ContentPane';
        $('#ContentPane').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('#MainMenu li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#ContentPane').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#ContentPane').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#ContentPane').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code, or at least a description of the problem.

Comment: JS Lint (press the 'JS Lint' button to the top of the window) [reports a  few problems](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Aw7v6/).

Comment: I'm not that strong with jquery yet thats why i used the guide from tutsplus

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if you are trying to load pages within your own domain.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="LeftPane">
<div id="Logo">
    <h1>Mats Ulrik Krüger</h1>
</div>
<div >
    <ul id="MainMenu">
        <li><a href="yourpage.php">JO Informatik</a></li>
        <li><a href="nextpage.html">Annemette Digmann</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
  <script>

   var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  var href = $('#MainMenu li a').each(function(){
 var href = $(this).attr('href');
 if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
    var toLoad = hash+'.html #ContentPane';
    $('#ContentPane').load(toLoad)
 }                                           
  });

  $('#MainMenu li a').click(function(){

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
$('#ContentPane').hide('fast',loadContent);
$('#load').remove();
$('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
$('#load').fadeIn('normal');
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
function loadContent() {
    $('#ContentPane').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#ContentPane').show('normal',hideLoader());
}
function hideLoader() {
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
}
return false;

   });
      </script>
```

you can post the error of firebug console if you still have problem